# How can I delete "SharedPreferences" data manually in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, caching, sharedpreferences, delete-file

It seems the `SharedPreferences` has stored some previous data like `token` from my app's previous running `SharedPreferences.getInstance().setString()` and I can see this by hovering mouse over `token` variable for example. But this stored preferences cause an error when I want to re-run the application. I tried `flutter clean` but it didn't work. How can I manually remove data from `SharedPreferences` without putting some code like `SharedPreferences.clear()` within the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove `SharedPreferences` cache just go to app info in phone settings and clear the app cache data.

[image]